# Which VGA Card is best suited for ASUS H81M-C motherboard?

Tags: graphics-cards, desktop

My old graphics card (NVIDIA GTX 660 2GB) is broken. I'd like to buy a new one that is better than my old card.

My issue is :

My PC can't be turned on more than a second. It immediately turns off. When I removed my graphics card, it starts up normally. I have tried 3 other cards. Two of them are working fine and my computer turned on normally. The other one gives me problems like my old card. I haven't tried to change the PSU or have my friend try my old card yet.

My current spec:

- Intel i3 Processor
- ASUS H81M-C motherboard
- Corsair 2x 4GB RAM
- ASUS NVDIA GTX 660 VGA Card
- Enermax 500W PSU

The graphics card I'm looking for:

- NVIDIA GeForce (any manufacturer, preferably well-known one)
- Better than current card (Higher than GTX 660)
- Minimum of 4GB
- Reasonably Priced (My budget $250-$300)
- Long lasting (not giving much problem such as overheat, fan problem, noise, etc if I run my PC overnight for days)

I will be using this card primarily for gaming and video editing purposes.

Comment: Before you blame the VGA card, check whether your PSU is dying. Do that by switching the PSU out with a known-good PSU from a friend or something, and if possible put the VGA in his computer to see whether the problem follows the VGA card around or not.

Comment: I'd get a GTX 1060 or 1070.

Comment: I confirm what @AdamWykes said. If you don't have an old psu lying around, compare the voltage requirements for the 4 cards... if the two with lower wattage requirements work, its most likely the power supply.

Comment: My VGA is broken. I'm really sure of it.

Comment: As long as you have a pci-e x16 slot and a big enough power supply **any** video card should work.